# Android - make whole area hyperlinked instead of just text?

Tags: android, hyperlink

Would really appreciate some help with this.

I have an app which consists of a gallery, text and icons. What i want to do is similar to the android market (example can be seen below). In the android market a whole area is hyperlinked rather than just the text. Hold your finger on one of the apps and it will light up green. That whole area is a hyperlink. Like below:

Looking to get something like this: http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/691/09droid3295x440.jpg

Is there anyway i can do that to my app? I have a very similar app, the gallery is right at the top with icons down the left and text besides each icon. I'm a bit of a newbie so i'm using nested linearlayouts with textviews and imageviews in each one.

Is there a way that it can be done? Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but that link is not working. I get a timeout, at least.

Comment: Use a ListView, that way each row is automatically "linked", as the Market application does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i misunderstood the question i'll give the correct answer here. If i understand right, you want to have an clickable View (in this case a `LinearLayout`) :

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutId);

layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Or any view for that matter (could be a Button, TextView, etc).

Comment: Appreciate all the help you are giving. Im guessing i need to import something to get "LinearLayout" working? and then the link/newpage that is the destination can go in the brackets of "new View.OnClickListener()"? Got R.id.layoutId working.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to flag the answer as the correct if this was the correct answer for you :)

Comment: Of course, will do! Can you just confirm what needs to be edited in the code? got layoutid down but nothing else. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to do when you click it. if you just want to start a new activity do: starActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), NameOfActivity.class);

Comment: Basically want it to open a new page, internally.

Comment: i'm guessing you don't really know what activities are. you should read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html but still my previous comment does that exactly.

Comment: What do i replace intent with? Thats chucking up a "cannot be resolved" error now. Before i put that bit in however the application ran but clicking in the view did nothing. Probably because i had nothing for it to do but now that i do "intent" is throwing up errors.

Comment: Ok, i'm using startActivity(new Intent(this, newjavafile.class)); instead and i have imported the content.intent but now the error reads as "The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<Linktext>) is undefined. Linktext being the new class i have already created for this.

Comment: force close :'( Anything i need to put in my main.xml or the new class?

startActivity(new Intent(SellScreen.this, Linktext.class))

Comment: LinkText class needs to extends the Activity class

Answer (score 0):

you could do the following to achieve this:

```
Spannable spans = (Spannable) text;
ClickableSpan clickSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://"
               + url));
    }

    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        // override link-centric text appearance
    }
};
int index = (text.toString()).indexOf(url);
spans.setSpan(clickSpan, index, url.length() + index, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Where text is your CharSequence.

Comment: Thanks for replying, sorry to be a pain but i'm a bit of a newbie and have no idea how to implement this. I can create a class called "Spannable" and cope the code in. However i don't what needs to be eidted and how it can be linked to my text which is in my xml file.

Comment: You don't need to create a class "Spannable" as this is included in the SDK. Just copy this code and create 2 variables: url and text. url is the url it should go to text is the charsequence (your text to click)

Comment: i just saw your new link. this code is to linkify text only. you just want to have a clickable row? use "setOnClickListener()" method of that row then.

Comment: Ah ok, thing is I'm not using a ListView so no rows are defined, simple linearlayout in main.xml

Answer (score 0):

Link not working

To answer ur query, create the link on the layout rather than text

Comment: Thanks for replying, my text is in my layout but a simple hyperlink won't do what i'm asking will it? Link should be working now too.